# Cosmic circles and the celestial key

Tags: wordplay, visual, cipher

**These seven cosmic circles appeared in the night sky:**

[image: Seven Cosmic Circles]

**For some reason, I was reminded of something my great uncle gave me long ago.  It was like a disk, but he called it a "celestial key".  He told me to hold on to it and that I would know when and how to use it.**

**Here, I found it:**

[image: Celestial Key]

**Starting from the dart, I see that it has the word BLINDING on it.**

**I held the celestial key at arm's length and lifted it up to the first cosmic circle.  It was a perfect fit.**

[image: Celestial key fits cosmic circle]

**I tried various orientations until I reached this one....**

[image: Rotate the celestial key within the cosmic circle]

**....and then, magically, several corresponding letters switched positions between the cosmic circle and the celestial key.**

[image: Magic happens]

**I noticed that the word on the celestial key changed from BLINDING to BRANDING.  Meanwhile, the cosmic circle now reads "LIFECANO" which at first seemed like more gibberish, until I realized that it could be parsed as "LIFE CAN O——" or maybe "LIFE CANO——".  The beginning of a message, maybe?**

**With the celestial key now showing BRANDING, I tried to fit it to a few other cosmic circles at various orientations, but no further magic occurred.  Maybe I don't understand which order the cosmic circles need to be visited.  Can you help me complete the message?**

Text version:

```
(Visiting the cosmic circles in clockwise order.
Withing each cosmic circle, traveling around the text in clockwise order.)

RAFECANO

ERDTOODB

TUTLTMUS

FWRWARGS

NLYBEUIS

ACKWORLS

DBEOIVED
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first step is given, yielding LIFECANO-BRANDING

from there, we can see NLYBE... which seems a promising start to the sentence,

> plugging in our celestial key, oriented SE, shifts the system to NLBEUND-BRAISING
>  ERDTOODB looks like understood, which fits the sentence, orient the key W, and the system becomes ERSTOODB-BRAIDING

Around here is where I recognized the quote, and flew threw the rest

> ACKWARDS-BROILING
>  BUTITMUS-TROLLING
>  TBELIVED-DROOLING
>  FORWARDS-GROWLING

Answer (score 5):

Please upvote @Sconibulus's answer.  This is just an illustration of the solution's journey around the cosmic circles.  (Each cosmic circle and celestial key is shown in its "post-magic" state.)

> [image: Solution journey]

The quote is

> “Life can only be understood backwards; but it must be lived forwards.”
>   — Soren Kierkegaard